# What Bhagavad-Gita says about responding to those who hurt you?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, dharma-shastras

What Bhagavad-Gita says about responding to those who hurt you? Do we need to stay calm and get hurt again and again untill our life ends and get the whole life spoiled because of bad people? Or else do we need to wait for the God's next incarnation? Or else leave them saying that God will punish them after death?

Comment: You are forgetting why Krishna gave Geeta updesha to Arjuna in the first place. Korwas hurt them(Padwas). And Pandwa's elders also taking side of Korwas(for diff reasons). Arjuna said to Krishna _"I can't fight with my own family. God will surely punish him then why I need to kill my own brothers/Grand Father/Guru"_ Then Krishna gave Geeta updesha to Arjuna to teach about Dharma. One must not surrender himself against adharma. But one has to kill all adharmies Even if it is your own relatives. Geeta promotes to take action against bad instead of sitting quitely and leave everything on God.

Comment: The key reason of Geeta updesha was to promote Arjuna to fight against bad instead of keep hurt by korwas and leave everything on God by thinking God will punish them some day.

Comment: @Rishabh, i don't know why, but i just find your spelling of kauravas as korwas to be hilarious :), i hope i don't offend you or anything, maybe it's a regional thing, but it's just sounds funny when i say it in my head..

Comment: @ram I am not offended at all bro. It's just, spell-check feature only works on English words. And kauravas is a Hindi word written in English. So spell-check feature can't correct me there. And without spell-check I am pretty useless in spelling hahaha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How to rightly act in a given situation, is part of *Dharma*. Bhagavad Gita doesn't discuss on general Dharma in the scope of *prakruti*. Refer:
[What is Dharma according to the Bhagavad Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20876/1049)

According to Gita, a person doesn't "act" under his own will.

> BG 5.8, 5.9 — "'I' certainly don't do anything" is believed by knower of fundamentals (*tattva gyAna*) - even while seeing, hearing, touching, smelling, eating, moving, dreaming, breathing, talking, discarding, accepting, opening, closing; -- "Senses only are acting in the subjects of senses" - is understood.

Hence this Qn may not be in the scope of Bhagavad Gita. You may want to ask from the perspective of *Dharma ShAstra* to get the precise answer.

---

However, for your specific Qn during Gita's discourse Krishna does ask Arjuna to fight without giving way to weakness:

> BG 2.3 - O Partha, yield not to unmanliness. This does not befit you. O scorcher of foes, arise, giving up the petty weakness of the heart.